# Why does the browser return unexpected end of input when I can get the API response from browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I have a very basic react front end and a very basic nodejs server.

I'm trying to validate the username and password on the server when the client clicks submit and then eventually redirect them to their dashboard.
Right now I am not able to go any further than sending the request for user data.

This is my very basic authentication function on the server, functions like authenticate and searchusers are not asynchronous.

```
// Authorization
app.get('/auth/:userId/:hash', function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.userId.toString();
  var hash = req.params.hash.toString();
  var error = {
    err: 'something went wrong!'
  }
  var user = dm.searchUser(id, users);
  if (!user){
    res.json(error);
  }
  var isAuthenticated = dm.authenticate(user, hash);
  if (!isAuthenticated){
    res.json(error);
  }
  if(isAuthenticated){
    console.log('authed')
    res.json(user);
  }
});
```

and this is my client side react component method that handles the submit action of a form.

```
  submit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3001/auth/"
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}${this.state.userId}/${this.state.password}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(json=>{console.log(json)})
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

From what I have tried, if I tried to send a request from my browser, the server does respond with my JSON data.

[image: View browser output when requested directly to the API using browser]

But when I try to do the same with my client, it gives back an error, can someone please help me out with what is going wrong?

[EDIT]

This is the error I get
[image: Error logged from catch()]

[image: And this is the headers in the network tab]

Comment: Can you put down the error here? It might be that your state params are not correct, but it'd be really easy if you put forward your error!

Comment: `mode: 'no-cors'` - **guarantees** no access to response - *no-cors — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not add or override any headers .... In addition, **JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response*** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Comment: `it gives back an error` - should we guess what the error is? or will you share it?

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, but don't forget to send an appropriate content-type header

Comment: Yeah I have added screenshots of the error

Comment: I also added screenshots of the header file

Comment: For debugging purposes, after `fetch` can you just have this: `.then(response=>console.log(response))` and see what you have?

Comment: This is probably some syntax error in your App.js. One thing that needs to be noted about axios is it catches the javascript errors as well that has been performed inside the then clause. Can you update your app.js file here.

Comment: @strah I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "see what you have"..

Comment: @duwalanise axios?

Comment: It should've been 'what you get', I suppose. I meant that you check a raw data coming from fetch, before even attempting to parse. @buoyantair

Comment: sorry i mean fetch request. @buoyantair